# Regular expression to have at-least one alphabet, one number & one special character

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

This is a JS regular expression to have at-least one alphabet, one number & one special character in any string.

```js
var pattern = /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%\^&*\(\)\-_+=;:'"\/\[\]{},.<>|`])/i
pattern.test("Test123!@#")
```

How do we write same regex in C#?

Comment: How about using the [`RegEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class?

Comment: FYI, This was a JS regular expression to have at-least one alphabet, one number & one special character in any string. and Thanks for your answers for helping me write this in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("Test123!@#",
              @"^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%\^&*\(\)\-_+=;:'""\/\[\]{},.<>|`])", 
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The double-quote character inside the verbatim string needs to be doubled up.

Comment: @Nailuj my bad - `"` should be `""` to escape

Comment: @ChristianHayter yeah - Ignored it carelessly, updated the code, and thanks to you and Nailuj for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
Match match = Regex.Match("Test123!@#", @"/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%\^&*\(\)\-_+=;:'""\/\[\]{},.<>|`])/i",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


if (match.Success)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? Regex is a Documented Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: Have you even tried compiling it yourself? It's quite a complicated expression with lots of special characters, so you can't simply just put it in a Regex (no, it doesn't help with the @ in front). One error is for instance: error CS1056: Unexpected character '\'.

Comment: The double-quote character inside the verbatim string needs to be doubled up.

Comment: Was your Question about how to port it to C#? or how to make sure your Regex with special characters is properly parsed in C#? your question doesnt seem to reflect what you want.

Comment: anyways ... i have updated the answer ... thanks Christian Hayter!

Comment: @Akhil .. FYI, This was a JS regular expression to have at-least one alphabet, one number & one special character in any string. and Thanks for your answers for helping me write this in C#.